# Lokesh Dhakar's Lightbox not showing image (although traces show it's working!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I'm implementing Lokesh Dhakar's Lightbox for a site I constructed for a friend maybe 15 years ago -- forgive the legacy HTML!

I've gotten it to work fine on two pages, but on the third the images don't appear.  I put `console.log` statements in the Lightbox source and it *seems* to be working -- the image is added to the album, the overlay is positioned, the image is changed and shown, according to the console.

But nothing shows up!  There's no error, no nothing.

The basic lightbox implementation is like this

```
        <td class="whitebg"><p><a class="thumblink"
                  href="/pd/images/puppet_postcard.jpg"
                  data-lightbox="image4"
                  data-title="Puppeteers Union Sq."><img
                    src="images/2014_images/puppet_thumb.jpg" width="130"
                      border="0"><br>
                        Puppeteers Union Sq.<br>
                        <span class="thumblink2">8.5&quot; x 13&quot;<br>
  Color Etching<br>
  2006<br>
  $200</span></a></p>

                    </td>
```

This is really frustrating, as I just did two pages that worked fine, and as far as I can see this one should as well -- it's not rocket science after all :-)  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, it *might* help to add the lightbox css to the page.  :-)

```
    <link href="/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Trying to work too quickly!